# He squandered the money { on / in } gambling?

Tags: prepositions

1. He squandered the money *in gambling*.
2. He squandered the money *on gambling*.

I think **in gambling** is correct, but when I speak **on gambling**, that also sounds correct. I think both are correct.

If it is so, what is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

*Gambling* is the action he's taking.  So you'd simply say:

> He squandered money gambling.

Which has an implied *while* in it, and could also be written:

> He squandered money while gambling.

Or:

> He squandered money with his gambling.

"He squandered money on gambling", as you suggested in your question, is also correct.  Instead of *gambling* being an action, in this sentence it's the noun of the concept of gambling in general.

You can't say "He squandered money in gambling", though; *to squander money on* is *to waste money for the purpose of*...  So *on* makes sense here.  *In* just doesn't apply.

Comment: I think *while* could have a slightly different meaning.  *while gambling* could mean that he didn't necessarily gamble his money away but rather spent it frivolously during the time he was gambling- maybe trying to hit on the waitress or something.

Answer (score 3):

"He squandered the money **on gambling**" is correct, as is "He squandered the money **in a Las Vegas casino**", as is "He squandered the money **gambling**". All idiomatic American English. Other varieties may have different ways of saying it.